# How to format a Canonical link with a paginated site

Tags: seo, search-engine, canonical-link

What is the best approach for formatting Canonical links on a search engine style website? At the minute our search engine fetches results and paginates them. We currently set the Canonical URL paginated pages back to the 1st page so:

**Examples**

http://jobportfolio.co.uk/jobs/any/london
Canonical = http://www.jobportfolio.co.uk/jobs/any/london

http://jobportfolio.co.uk/jobs/any/london/?&page=2
Canonical = http://www.jobportfolio.co.uk/jobs/any/london

Is this the best approach or should I be setting the Canonical URL to also include the &page=2?

I noticed that when I submitted the XML Sitemap only a small fraction of the pages were indexed.

Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use `canonical` for pages/URLs with (almost) identical content. Your pagination pages clearly have *different* content.

Comment: Thanks, I had noticed that quite a few sites seem to revert back to page 1 of the search results. I wonder if this has any benefit.